# fetching data from json using php?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, json

I have a Json data retrieved from facebook using graph api, now i am going to parse that data, i decoded that json

```
$decodedjson= json_decode($jsondata);
```

after that i got data in following format.
[image: Image for Json data]

i write

```
$id= $decodedjson->message_id;
```

to get the id, 
the attachment is an other object, please tell me how can i access the attachment, media, href, alt and the video , display_url and so on, name etc

Thanks

Comment: If you have difficulty traveresing objects, have you considered using arrays instead? If you provide `true` for the second variable in `json_decode($jsondata,true);`, it returns an assoc array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like any object -

```
$vid=($decodedjson[2])->attachment->media[0];
$alt=$vid->alt;
```

**Edit:** Noticed the `[2]=>...` at the top of your `var_dump`

Comment: when i used it says Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\display\index.php

Comment: I've just noticed that this is a partial var_dump by the looks of it. If you're going to post a var dump, post the dump of the whole object - it looks like $decodedjson is in fact an array of objects based on the `[2] =>...` at the top...

Answer (score 0):

json_decode - convert json format to php array
You should access it as array

```
$id= $decodedjson[0]['message_id'];
```

```
 $attachment= $decodedjson[0]['attachment']['media'];//an array

$video= $decodedjson[0]['media'][0]['video']['owner'];
```

Comment: he's `var_dumped` it, it's clearly a `stdClass`, this answer doesn't add anything...

Comment: $id= $decodedjson[0]['message_id'];  is not correct because message_id is object and it will be accessed using $decodedjson[0]->message_id;